# How can I leverage a variable as a column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following error when I try to use a variable as a column name.

**Error**

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
>   Invalid column name '@WKNUM'.

**Code**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @WKNUM int

SET @WKNUM = 17
WHILE (@WKNUM < 20)
BEGIN;

    UPDATE dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM
    SET dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.[@WKNUM] = dbo.TEST2.[New Value]
    FROM dbo.TEST2
    INNER JOIN dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM
        ON dbo.TEST2.[Opportunity ID] = dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.opportunityID
    WHERE (dbo.TEST2.WKNUM = @WKNUM)

    SET @WKNUM = @WKNUM + 1
END;
GO
SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Any idea why it is giving this error?

Comment: you can't use a variable for a column name like that. Use dynamic sql instead.

Comment: Please describe more, what do exactly you want to do? I confused that you want to change name of a column or you want to add a new column or you want to update some columns or may be another thing ;).

Comment: That looks like a terribly inefficient way to attempt to perform a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you cannot use variables as column names as you are attempting:

Best would be to build the update string including all variables and then executing it once completed:

```
DECLARE @SqlString VARCHAR(1000)
SET @SqlString = 'UPDATE dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM SET dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.[' + @WKNUM + '] = dbo.TEST2.[New Value]
                  FROM dbo.TEST2 INNER JOIN dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM ON dbo.TEST2.[Opportunity ID] = dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.opportunityID
                  WHERE (dbo.TEST2.WKNUM = ' + @WKNUM + ' )  '

EXEC(@SqlString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM
SET    dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.[@WKNUM] = dbo.TEST2.[New Value]------What you are try to do here ...!!!
 ---you can not define column name like this..
FROM   dbo.TEST2
INNER JOIN
dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM ON dbo.TEST2.[Opportunity ID] = dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.opportunityID
WHERE        (dbo.TEST2.WKNUM = @WKNUM )
```

you define **@WKNUM** as **INT** that will give you value 17,18,19..
is it confirm that you have **column name** like this...if it is then you have to use dynamic sql like this..

```
DECLARE @update VARCHAR(1000)
SET @update = 'UPDATE dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM SET dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.[' + @WKNUM + '] = dbo.TEST2.[New Value]
                  FROM dbo.TEST2 INNER JOIN dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM ON dbo.TEST2.[Opportunity ID] = dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.opportunityID
                  WHERE (dbo.TEST2.WKNUM = ' + @WKNUM + ' )  '

EXEC(@update )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one issue I found that you used variable name instead of actual column name.

```
begin  tran
create table DataModel_TEST_NUM (opportunityID int, WKNUM int )
create table TEST2 (opportunityID int, WKNUM int, new_value int )

insert into DataModel_TEST_NUM values (1, 18) , (2,25 ),(3,19 ), (4,30)

insert into TEST2 values (1, 18, 19) , (2 ,25 ,26 ),(3,19, 20 ), (4,30,31)


--SET NOCOUNT ON
--GO
select * from DataModel_TEST_NUM

DECLARE @WKNUM int

SET @WKNUM = 17
WHILE (@WKNUM < 20)
BEGIN;

    UPDATE dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM
    SET [WKNUM] = dbo.TEST2.[new_value]
    --select *
    FROM dbo.TEST2
    INNER JOIN dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM
        ON dbo.TEST2.[opportunityID] = dbo.DataModel_TEST_NUM.opportunityID
    WHERE (dbo.TEST2.WKNUM = @WKNUM)

    SET @WKNUM = @WKNUM + 1
END;
--GO
--SET NOCOUNT OFF
--GO

select * from DataModel_TEST_NUM
select * from test2

rollback 

--actual data
opportunityID   WKNUM
    1           18
    2           25
    3           19
    4           30

--after while loop and update query 
opportunityID   WKNUM
    1           19
    2           25
    3           20
    4           30
```

I have some suggestion for you.

1. While testing `SET NOCOUNT` option is always off.
2. Alywas follow the standarad rule when you create a table, in your case you give space in column name. Never create this type of column-name.